# The yield + recursion in python annoyed me

Tags: python, recursion, yield

It is so complicated for me to  understand  when  yield and recursion happen simultaneously。
I want to traverse  file directory with my code:

```
import os
def doc_iter(fpath):
  if os.path.isdir(fpath):
    for child in os.listdir(fpath):
      child=os.path.join(fpath,child)
      print  "this is ",child
      for cn in doc_iter(child):
        print "i am here1"
        yield cn
        print "yiedl1",cn
  else:
    print "i am here2"
    yield fpath
    print "yield2",fpath
```

There is a diretory `test` ,three child directory `test1,test2,test3` in it
In  directory `test1` ,there are two files `test11,test12`
In  directory `test2` ,there are two files `test21,test22`
In  directory `test3` ,there are two files `test31,test32`

```
    >>> a.next()
this is  /home/debian/test/test2
this is  /home/debian/test/test2/test22
i am here2
i am here1
i am here1
'/home/debian/test/test2/test22'
>>> a.next()
yiedl1 /home/debian/test/test2/test22
yiedl1 /home/debian/test/test2/test22
yield2 /home/debian/test/test2/test22
this is  /home/debian/test/test2/test21
i am here2
i am here1
i am here1
'/home/debian/test/test2/test21'
>>> a.next()
yiedl1 /home/debian/test/test2/test21
yiedl1 /home/debian/test/test2/test21
yield2 /home/debian/test/test2/test21
this is  /home/debian/test/test3
this is  /home/debian/test/test3/test32
i am here2
i am here1
i am here1
'/home/debian/test/test3/test32'
>>> a.next()
yiedl1 /home/debian/test/test3/test32
yiedl1 /home/debian/test/test3/test32
yield2 /home/debian/test/test3/test32
this is  /home/debian/test/test3/test31
i am here2
i am here1
i am here1
'/home/debian/test/test3/test31'
>>> a.next()
yiedl1 /home/debian/test/test3/test31
yiedl1 /home/debian/test/test3/test31
yield2 /home/debian/test/test3/test31
this is  /home/debian/test/test1
this is  /home/debian/test/test1/test11
i am here2
i am here1
i am here1
'/home/debian/test/test1/test11'
>>> a.next()
yiedl1 /home/debian/test/test1/test11
yiedl1 /home/debian/test/test1/test11
yield2 /home/debian/test/test1/test11
this is  /home/debian/test/test1/test12
i am here2
i am here1
i am here1
'/home/debian/test/test1/test12'
>>> a.next()
yiedl1 /home/debian/test/test1/test12
yiedl1 /home/debian/test/test1/test12
yield2 /home/debian/test/test1/test12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

The output  annoyed me,
1.The print in yield 1  is equal to in yield 2?
2.There are at least two yield statement to run,in textbook,it is said`when run into yield ,the program will be halt, the next next() make it continue`??
3.let's analyse  the output of first next(),why there are two  `i am here1`s  after `i am here2" 
4.what is the function of`yield cn`?
5.how to draw the calculation tree in detail?
6.if you write a function to traverse the directory,

```
bottom=[]
import os 
def doc_iter(fpath):
    if os.path.isdir(fpath):
        for child in os.listdir(fpath):
            child=os.path.join(fpath,child)
            doc_iter(child)
    else:
        bottom.append(fpath)
    return bottom
```

the output is :

```
doc_iter("/home/debian/test")
```

['/home/debian/test/test2/test22', '/home/debian/test/test2/test21', '/home/debian/test/test', '/home/debian/test/test3/test32', '/home/debian/test/test3/test31', '/home/debian/test/test~', '/home/debian/test/test1/test11', '/home/debian/test/test1/test12']

there are different between the function and  iterator,
in the function:

```
doc_iter(child)
```

in the iterator :

```
for cn in doc_iter(child):
    yield
```

how complicated it is in this example!

Comment: This code puts the "fun" in function.

Comment: You might be able to better see what's happening if you also add print statements before each yield. When you print after a yield, the print doesn't happen until the *next* `next()` call, which seems to be confusing things more than necessary.

Comment: why don't you use os.walk() function?? it also uses generator, so you can easily use next()...

Answer (score 1):

So your example here is a bit contrived and leads to most if not all the difficulty you are having with understanding how `yield` works.

Each iteration of the `walk_dir` results in a new root path being passed to the entire function which will result in a new iteration of the function with its own `yields`

Now the reason you are seeing the same path printed is because each invocation of next moves  the deeper into the directory structure.

So each `next()` returns the next directory or file. The stop iteration exception you are seeing is how the idiom

`for x in something_that_yeilds()` knows how to stop.

I would look at this pretty awesome write up on [iterators, iterable, and generators](http://excess.org/article/2013/02/itergen1/).